# What is [Full GC (Allocation Failure)

Tags: java, performance, jvm

I am seeing Allocation failure in Full GC logging message.

What is Allocation Failure when Full GC?

Is it safe to ignore?

Comment: are you actually experiencing any problems?

Comment: I am not experiencing any problems but got this message while doing performance testing on our dev application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Allocation failure means that there was no enough contiguous memory available in the heap to allocate. GC runs as a result of allocation failure. If there is enough space available after GC has completed then all is good. Allocation failure is different from GC failure. GC failure happens when even after GC has completed there is not enough space available to assign to process.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you need to set arguments before starting application i.e. heap size. Though running GC is not mandatory, but while testing, if you run GC from application, it can give you pointer( Maybe you need to go to boundary scenario stop the world).

Answer (score 0):

During the GC time,when there is no enough space to store a number of objects which are copied from the eden/survivor region,we need to allocate space from the tenured generation.Full GC means that stop-the-world happens